# What is USE in php?

Tags: php

What does `USE` do in php?  I thought it was like `include()` but apparently I'm wrong.  Could somebody point me to the php documentation on `USE` and maybe some example code?

Comment: not to be rude, but googling "php use" will get you the appropriate documentation page

Comment: The use keyword allows you to introduce local variables into the local scope of an anonymous function. This is useful in the case where you pass the anonymous function to some other function which you have no control over. [Source.](http://blog.dubbelboer.com/2012/04/07/php-use-keyword.html) Took me about 3 second's of using Google, perhaps you could try the same before you post?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`use` has two uses:

1. [Namespaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php)
2. [Anonymous Functions, aka Closures](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Comment: Anonymous functions are not also known as closures, they are two different things.

Comment: @GaryWilloughby OK, then which definition fits what PHP has implemented? Is it an anonymous function without the `use` keyword, but a semi-closure when `use` *is* used? And what about the fuzzy logic internal to PHP where anonymous functions are represented by objects named 'Closure'?